# How to reference a theorem number in a page header?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, header-footer, memoir

I would like to use the `headings` *pagestyle* of *memoir*, but LaTeX complains about missing references due to some sections named like `Proof of Theorem~\ref{theorem_label}`. Is there a way to fix this other than hard-coding the theorem number through the optional arguments of the `\section` command?

*Update 1:* It appears that the culprit is the *hyperref* package. Here is a minimal working example; note that the `\clearpage` are needed to force the creation of a page with the reference in the header, since otherwise the document compiles without issues.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A theorem}

\begin{theorem}
  \label{thm:fermat}
  There are no non-trivial integer solutions to $x^n + y^n = z^n$ for $n > 2$.
\end{theorem}

\clearpage

\section{Proof of Theorem~\ref{thm:fermat}}

\clearpage

See Wiles.

\end{document}
```

I am still at a loss, though. The only thing I can find in the manual of *memoir* is that the *memhfixc* package is needed to fix incompatibilities with *hyperref*, which is loaded automatically. However, even loading it explicitly doesn't fix the issue.

*Update 2:* The issue seems to be due to the uppercasing of the label. Somehow *hyperref* mangles the `\uppercaseheads` macro from *memoir*, which is defined using `\MakeTextUppercase` from *textcase*. As a workaround, one can use `\nouppercaseheads`, although that seems like a sub-optimal solution.

Comment: What happens if you change `\section{Proof of Theorem \ref{theorem_label}}` to `\section{Proof of Theorem \protect\ref{theorem_label}`?

Comment: @Mico It doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: In that case, you really have to provide more information about what's ailing your document, ideally in the form of a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001)
 that begins with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, and generates the problem behavior you wish to fix. So far, unfortunately, you have not provided such information. Incidentally, you do have a `\label\ref{theorem_label}` directive somewhere in the document, right?

Comment: @Mico Of course, \label{theorem_label} is defined elsewhere in the document, which compiles with no errors using the `plain` _pagestyle_.

Comment: I was unable to replicate this. You did run twice to get references on the second run, correct?

Comment: @DonHosek Correct. I usually compile my documents with `latexmk`, which takes care of it automatically, but this also happens if I use `pdflatex` directly. I'll try to write a minimal (not) working example.

Comment: @Mico I have now added an MWE. Sorry for the poor quality of my initial question.

Comment: So the problem is caused by the `hyperref` package and it's causing the label name to get uppercase applied to it. Putting this here if anyone else cares to tackle this... I may come back to it later if I'm so inclined.

Comment: This does appear to be a bug in `hyperref`. And I'm sad to discover that Sebastian Rahtz is no longer with us. 

Comment: This is an ugly hack, but you could try defining the label all uppercase, and then also using `\protect\ref` in the section name.

Comment: @barbarabeeton making the label all uppercase would be sufficient. The `\protect` isn't necessary.

Comment: @barbarabeeton My e-mail is don.hosek at gmail.com (I don't know if you still have the ams e-mail).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the issue is due to a bug in *hyperref*. There are at least two possible workarounds that preserve the general feel of the `headings` pagestyle:

1. Use small-caps headings:

```
\nouppercaseheads           % Disable automatic capitalisation
\pagestyle{headings}
\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{}{\slshape\scshape\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\slshape\scshape\rightmark}{}{\thepage}
```

2. As suggested by @barbarabeeton in the comments, use all-caps labels where the error occurs.